# How to calculate the adjacent pixel correlation for the original plaintext image in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have tried to calculate adjacent pixel correlation of 2 images. I am getting the answer for the encrypted images but not for the original plain text image.

It's showing some error which i am unable to understand. I have given the code which i used below along with the error message.

Please help.

```
P = imread('cameraman.tif');
x1 = P(:,1:end-1); 
y1 = P(:,2:end);
r_xy1 = corrcoef(x1,y1);
scatter(x1,y1);
```

For this I am getting an error message:

> Error using bsxfun Mixed integer class inputs are not supported.
>
> Error in cov (line 93)   xc = bsxfun(@minus,x,sum(x,1)/m);  % Remove
>   mean
>
> Error in corrcoef>correl (line 209) r = cov(x);
>
> Error in corrcoef (line 92)    r = correl(x);
>
> Error in apc_PT (line 4) r_xy1 = corrcoef(x1,y1);

The same code worked for encrypted image. Dont know what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You should cast the result of `imread` to double:

```
P = double(imread(...));
```

This will fix your error with `corrcoef`.

**Edit** Also, as noticed in the comments you have to use vectors in `scatter`:

```
scatter(x1(:), y1(:));
```

Best,

Comment: The `scatter` call gives the following error. `Error using scatter (line 44)
X and Y must be vectors of the same length.` Please add this line to your solution: `scatter(x1(:),y1(:));`